# Dedicated Ip Address using vpn connection

Tags: networking, router, vpn, ip, firewall

I am a newbie in Network connections and I developing an application that needs to connect to a Server "Y", the connection is allowed just for an specific IP through the firewall, this IP must be a dedicated IP.

so all that being said, I have a concrete question:

> I have a dedicated IP in one "own" server, if I connect from an X computer
> to that "own" server connected through VPN, will my X computer be
> also using the dedicated IP from my "own" server to communicate with server "Y"?

Thanks in Advance for you helpful comments

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly the question,
the answer is usually No.

The VPN creates a virtual network interface that is
distinct from the physical interface. That means that
it serves a separate IP address range than the one used
before the VPN was started.

Each network interface, physical or virtual, will have
supplied your computer with an IP address in its own
IP address range, which can be static or dynamic.

This means that your computer cannot have the same IP address
on the physical network and the VPN network.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a dedicated IP in one "own" server, if I connect from an X computer to that "own" server connected through VPN, will my X computer be also using the dedicated IP from my "own" server to communicate with server "Y"?

In a sense, yes – not strictly always, as it depends on how the VPN server has been set up, but this is indeed one of the *main* uses of a VPN and usually it's easy to set it up to allow that.

(Many people route all their Internet use through a VPN server in this way, but you can configure the VPN client to route *just* communications with server Y if that's what you need.)

However, in the usual configuration, the client computer won't *directly* use the server's IP address (as harrymc explains); instead it will work much like your home router does, with "internal" addresses within the VPN connection and with the router doing NAT to swap the address before packets leave the system. Still, the result is that the traffic appears as if originated from the VPN server – your Server "Y" can't really tell the difference.

(It is also technically possible to "move" the VPN server's dedicated address to the VPN client, but that's a slightly more complex setup and usually requires the server to have at least two addresses.)

Most of the configuration is done "outside" the VPN software; e.g. with a Linux-based VPN server you'd be configuring a `MASQUERADE` rule in iptables, no matter what VPN software you chose.

Alternative option: Make your app support either HTTP 'CONNECT' proxies or SOCKS5 proxies. Both are widely supported and the configuration can be simpler than VPN. (For example, most SSH clients can emulate SOCKS5 without any configuration at all.)

Comment: Is there a way to test if my request go with the dedicated ip address? i have try with cmd but i do not see the ip address that the vpn gave me

Comment: The IP address that the VPN gives you will _not_ be the server's own address. (Literally because it is already the server's address!) You need to actually make a request to some external system (e.g. some "whatismyip" kind of service) and see whether that system sees requests as coming from the VPN server's address.